# $H=\bigoplus H_n$ is separable?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, separable-spaces

Let $(H_n)$ a collection enumerable of Hilbert spaces. Consider
$$
H=\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty H_n=\left\{(x_n):\sum_{n=1}^\infty\|x_n\|^2<\infty\right\}.
$$
If each $H_n$ is separable, then $H$ also is separable?

If $H_n=\mathbb{C}$ is immediately to check: $H=\ell_2(\mathbb{N})$. But, the problem is for arbitrary Hilbert space $H_n$.

----- EDIT -----

Maybe one way to resolve is using what Sambo commented. So, if I consider
$$
K=\bigoplus^{\operatorname{alg}}H_n=\left\{(x_n)\in H:x_n\neq0\mbox{ for finite choices of }x_n\right\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \times_{k=1}^n H_k\times_{k=n+1}^\infty\{0\},
$$
we have that $\overline{K}=H$. It's clear that $K$ is separable, since each $\times_{k=1}^n H_k\times_{k=n+1}^\infty\{0\}$ is separable, so the reunion must be separable too. Hence, $H$ is separable for being closure of $K$.

Comment: Hint: consider sequences which are eventually zero.

Comment: Union of  corresponding orthonormal basis for each $H_n$ will be an orthonormal basis for $H$.